# VBA to update multiple sheets from main spreadsheet based on department name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is used to track audit scores for 9 different departments in a plant.    The 9 departments are broken down to 117 different area locations. Once a month I add a new column and update the scores.  What I would like is a seperate sheet for each department with the audit scores updating automatically when I import the original data in.  I'm new to VBA programming and this may be over my head a little bit, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes.  There are multiple methods that can accomplish this sort of data segregation.  One way I can think of would accomplish this without VBA using justcell formulas.  What do you do with the score data after it is entered?  I assume there is some sort of total/avg type activity?

Comment: Yes, the data is used for departments averages to compare with the past months.

Comment: An easy design method I can think of. Make a worksheet tab for each dept. Then have the first row of that be your average line. Then create a summary tab that has a formula pulling in each tab's respective cell element.  For your references just do SheetName!Cell.  So something like Aquisitions!B2

Comment: You indicated that you wanted each departments scores updated automatically when you import the data-How do you import the data?

Comment: The data is currently being copied and pasted from a MySQL table to a column that I add each month in the main excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a pivot table in each tab ? 
You'll only have to use the "actualize" command once ( *Data-->Refresh all*) whenever you're adding a column. 
The thing you have ot be careful with is to set-up you master table as a  list (*Home tab-->Format as a table* command ) or else the pivot table will not take account of an added new column.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual data and the format the it is currently in...
Assuming that you make a separate sheet for each department each with a row corresponding to its respective area...
I would utilize a class to hook the application's events and update each sheet on the Worksheet_Change event. Chip Pearson provides an excellent example of this concept [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx) and I'm sure that a cursory search of SO will turn up quite a few examples as well.
From that point it is a matter of identifying the imported data and it's corresponding location in the workbook.
If you have an example I would be happy to look at it...